# How would you solve this system if linear equations in 3 variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The equations are-
$$
a+b+c=6 
$$
$$
ab+bc+ca=11
$$
$$
abc=6
$$
Also,is there a way to generalise this to a formula for varying values of the constants?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** $a,b,c$ are roots of the cubic equation
$$
x^3-6x^2+11x-6=0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+ac+bc)x-abc$

So the roots of $x^3-6x+11x-6=0$ will give you $a$, $b$, $c$.

Factorizing:

$$x^3-6x^2+11x-6=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$

So $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, $1,2,3$ will work. For cubics in class, the roots are always integers

Answer (score -2):

An elementary computation (to get to the same end result as in the same answers):

Use the first equation to find that 
$$
a=6-b-c.
$$

Substitute this into the second equation and solve for $b$ using the quadratic formula to get
$$
b=-\frac{1}{2}c+3\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-3c^2+12c-8}
$$

Substituting this into the third equation results in
$$
c^3-6c^2+11c=6
$$
(which then must be solved).